# What is the difference between these two styles for handling sequential Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

When we want to execute several then functions one after another in a sequential manner, what is the difference between these two styles:

1- To use nested thens

```js
$http.get('api').then(function(){
    processBlocks(obj.data).then(function(){
        alert('it is done')
    });
});
```

2- Flatten the nested thens

```js
$http.get('api').then(function(){
    return processBlocks(obj.data);
}).then(function(){
    alert('it is done')
});
```

It is obvious that the second one is more readable but is there a performance difference as well?

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that Angular now uses Observables, not Promises, for HTTP requests - which have their own idiomatic coding style.

Comment: The difference is that the second one is correct, and the first one is not.

Answer (score 3):

```
$http.get('api').then(function(){
    processBlocks(obj.data).then(function(){
        alert('it is done')
    });
});
```

In this case, if you concatenate another `then` like this:

```
$http.get('api').then(function(){
    processBlocks(obj.data).then(function(){
        alert('it is done')
    });
}).then(function(){
alert('it is done')
});
```

if `processBlocks()` throws an exception, it doesnt matter, and the next promise will be fired, but:

```
$http.get('api').then(function(){
    return processBlocks(obj.data);
}).then(function(){
    alert('it is done')
});
```

In this case, if the first `then` fails, the sequence is canceled and in case of having a `catch` block, it will be fired

Comment: It's worse than that. You can never further wait on the inner promise with the first example. If you add a `.then()` on the outside (because that's the promise that got returned), it will not wait on the completion of the inner Promise, only the outer one, since you did not return a Promise.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a very slight performance difference in that the function passed to a `.then` is chained with the initial chained Promise *when* the interpreter runs across the initial Promise on that line. To illustrate, when the Promises are all chained together in a flat manner, the second chained `expensiveFunctionThatReturnsFunc()` runs *immediately* in order to create the function to put in the `.then` chain:

```js
const resolveAfter = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const expensiveFunctionThatReturnsFunc = () => {
  console.log('making fn...');
  // for (let i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {}
  return () => console.log('resolving');
}

console.log('start');
resolveAfter(1000)
  .then(() => resolveAfter(1000))
  .then(expensiveFunctionThatReturnsFunc());
```

In contrast, when you have nested .`then`s, the `expensiveFunctionThatReturnsFunc()` will only run once the first `Promise` resolves:

```js
const resolveAfter = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const expensiveFunctionThatReturnsFunc = () => {
  console.log('making fn...');
  // for (let i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {}
  return () => console.log('resolving');
}

console.log('start');
resolveAfter(1000)
  .then(() => {
    return resolveAfter(1000)
    .then(expensiveFunctionThatReturnsFunc());
  });
```

Still, the effect of such a thing will be completely imperceptible in 99% of situations. Don't worry about it, better to just make your code readable.